# Find one solution for system of inequalities (if exists)

Tags: inequality

If there exists a solution for following system of inequalities, find at least one, else show that there is no solution exists.

$$x_4(x_1+x_7)>x_3(x_2+x_8)$$ 
$$x_3(x_5+x_8)>x_7(x_4+x_1)$$ 
$$x_7(x_6+x_4)>x_8(x_5+x_3)$$ 
$$x_8(x_3+x_2)>x_4(x_6+x_7)$$

for all $i$,  $0 < x_i <1$ and $\sum_i x_i=1$

Answer (score 0):

A quick computer simulation shows such solutions exist. Example:

A = (0.020302010304655, 0.052938093317538, 0.040635876493691, 0.016599197409892,  0.247812843241618, 0.120692838614077, 0.388175655457951, 0.112843485160578)

> > sum(A)

ans = 1

> > $A(4)*(A(1)+A(7))-A(3)*(A(2)+A(8))$

ans = 4.372166355951553e-05

> > $A(3)*(A(5)+A(8))-A(7)*(A(4)+A(1))$

ans = 3.314355258354201e-04

> > $A(7)*(A(6)+A(4))-A(8)*(A(5)+A(3))$

ans = 0.020743867247722

> > $A(8)*(A(3)+A(2))-A(4)*(A(6)+A(7))$

ans = 0.002112404285034

Comment: @ pharmine: Converting the elements of $A$ to rationals and adding those, one obtains $${\frac {112204726358063191347750231121831481}{
112204726389776842878359836410752160}},
 $$ not $1$.

Comment: @user64494 I'll check, but I think that can be dealt with without affecting inequality signs.

Comment: Thank you, I changed $A(8)$ to satisfy $A(1)+\cdots+A(8)=1$ and updated the results accordingly.

Comment: @ pharmine: For "updated values" one obtains the same $$ {\frac {112204726358063191347750231121831481}{
112204726389776842878359836410752160}}
.$$

Comment: Really? Even though $0.112843485160579$ was changed to $0.112843485160578$? You might need to refresh the page.

Comment: @ pharmine : The page was refreshed. Are you serious?

Comment: See [verification](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvd5xwh57el9ss0/verification.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: $A(1)=0.020302010304655=20302010304655/10^{15}$ and not equal to $326/160723$ etc. I don't see why you want to convert a finite decimal to a different rational number (circulating decimal).

Comment: @ pharmine: Sorry, but you note is not true: pay your attention to the conditions $0 < x_i <1, i=1,...,8 .$

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the note.